# Cloud Storage bandwidth is increasing rapidly when deploying Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I've started using Firebase functions recently and I've made the first deployment for 4 functions. I have observed that the Cloud Storage bandwidth increased by about 400 MB! Why this increase was so great?